# Forgot to eject! 1,0 TB Hard Drive is appearing in Disks, but it is not appearing in Files

Tags: 20.04, partitioning, hard-drive, filesystem, disk

I had a situation were I had to move the computer from where it was. I turned off the computer and just disconnected every USB including  the Hard Disk. Informations:

1. My Drive is plugged
2. I am trying to use my HD back again, off course, without loosing the files I already had.
3. I have tried to do  sudo fsck /dev/sdb  and it didn't work, I am now going to try chkdsk In windows.
4. I discovered that this drive is a NTFS (chkdsk is still loading).
5. CHKDSK is done, Windows showed this message in the cmd "It showed the text: "Windows verified the system of archives and did not find any problems" (translated from portuguese)."
6. chkdsk in terminal of ubuntu shows error message inside terminal "chkdsk: command not found
   ".

Now the Hard Disk is on and it is appearing in the Disks application. When I open the Disks application I only have these options available:
*"Format Partition..."
"create Partition Image..."
"Restore Partition Image..."
"Benchmark Partition..."*

[image]

Contents are appearing as unknown!
sudo fdisk -l

```
lima@Lima:~$ sudo fdisk -l
[sudo] password for lima: 


Disk /dev/sda: 111,82 GiB, 120040980480 bytes, 234455040 sectors
Disk model: WDC WDS120G2G0A-
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: CC468874-3D11-4188-B15B-A6C133003A42

Device       Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sda2  1050624 234452991 233402368 111,3G Linux filesystem
```

PS: I am going to edit the question instead of responding in the comments, thank you.

I just installed GParted in my Linux Ubuntu computer and a error message appeared.
here is a picture of the error message[image: description]
I pressed "Cancel" and this is what appeared.[image: description]

Comment: fsck or chkdsk won't help as Ubuntu didn't recognzize a partition or filesystem on the device /dev/sdb.
You should check dmesg-output for errors with the usb device or the usb storage-driver.
Maybe the drive doesn't get enough power from the usb-port. Let's first check the output, then see: dmesg|grep sdb dmesg|grep usb

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142615/discussion-on-question-by-mr-lima-forgot-to-eject-1-0-tb-hard-drive-is-appeari); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.